# MySql: How to use a defined Variable in select with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do some calculation with the columns and filter the results by using  where between the Low and High range. To get the final results I am using variables inside the select statement and when I am using the final value derived from the last calculations and using it with where clause it comes with 0 results found. Please refer to my sql code below:-

```
SELECT autorates.Buy AS 'Buy', Carrier.FuelLevy, 
@FuelLevyTotal := ((autorates.Buy * Carrier.FuelLevy) + autorates.Buy) AS 'withFuelLevyTotal', 
@FuelLevyGSTTotal := ((@FuelLevyTotal * 0.10) + @FuelLevyTotal) AS 'withGSTrate',  
@MarginTotal := ((Margin.Margin * @FuelLevyGSTTotal) + @FuelLevyGSTTotal) AS 'Sell',  // Final Results after all calculations
Margin.Low, Margin.High, autorates.OriginType, autorates.DestinationType, autorates.GoodsAllowed, Carrier.Disabled
FROM  Margin, autorates
LEFT JOIN Carrier on Carrier.ID = autorates.Carrier
WHERE autorates.Car='4WD/Van' AND autorates.Origin = 'Melbourne' AND autorates.Destination = 'Sydney' 
AND Carrier.Disabled  = 0 AND 
autorates.GoodsAllowed = 0  AND 
@MarginTotal BETWEEN Margin.Low and Margin.High           //Here is the problem
GROUP BY autorates.OriginType , autorates.DestinationType      
ORDER by @MarginTotal
```

The following screenshot are the result I am getting it when running, and which is wrong::

[image]

The formula to get the Sell is :

1. Buy * FuelLevy = withFuelLevyTotal
2. withFuelLevyTotal * 10%(GST) = withGSTrate. 
   Now I want this value to look into the Margin table and get the Margin between margin.low and margin.high range.
3. Sell = (withGSTrate * Margin ) + withGSTrate.

the following screenshot is the margin table.
[image]

And this screenshot below is the Fuellevy (i.e. 0.1604)

[image]

Comment: I want to use `@MarginTotal` in where clause to find between Low and High Value

Comment: can you share the table structure and data

Comment: How can I share the table structure and data here?? I dont have any clue. And the data inside this table has more than 100,000 records

Comment: you can share structure easily by dropping DDL here . you can also create example dataset to clarify your intention. Put some effort in if you ask for help

Comment: I doubt whether the group by will give the result you expect, rather than using user defined variables just repeat the calculation.

Comment: @P.Salmon I tried removing group by, however, i realized that my left join is not fetching the right results.

Comment: Did you really intend to create a cross join (FROM  Margin, autorates)? is there a way to join margin to autorates?

Comment: You could improve this question by adding the table definitions as text to your question (show create table <tablename> , then copy and paste), by adding sample data and expected output as text to the question , or create a sqlfiddle. Images aren't very useful especially if they don't have headers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a stored proc instead of a single query. Above query will not work. MarginTotal is variable defined in the query and cannot be used in the where statement. Inner Query can be used but it is bit complicated.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for suggestion. I am not able to get my head down. Can u please point out to some examples please

Comment: Please run the below queries and share the results
desc autorates;
desc margin;
desc carrier;

I would also need some sample data from the above tables. If there are too many records, share few rows atleast.
select * from autorates;
select * from carrier; 
select * from margin;